# Show a specific model property based on selected item

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I have this model:

```
public class Rent {

    private Integer priceDay;
    private Integer priceWeek;
    private Integer priceMonth;

    // ...
}
```

I would like to display the price of the desired term based on the price type chosen in a dropdown, which can be "day", "week" and "month". Currently, I've solved it as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.priceType}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Price" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="day" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="week" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="month" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.changePrice}" render="price" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:outputText id="price" value="#{bean.price}" />
```

with

```
public void changePrice(){
    if (priceType.compareTo("day") == 0) {
        price = rent.getPriceDay();
    } else if (priceType.compareTo("week") == 0) {
        price = rent.getPriceWeek();
    } else if (priceType.compareTo("month") == 0) {
        price = rent.getPriceMonth();
    }
}
```

However, I feel that this is clumsy and there should be an easier and more elegant way to achieve the same without the need for a whole if-else block and copies of the model properties in the controller. Is this possible?

Comment: EL runs in webserver, not in webbrowser. Maybe you had JavaScript in mind?

Comment: I was thinking something with JSF actually, but nothing came so far =]

Comment: How exactly is the current approach "inelegant"?

Comment: I had to create an `attribute` in `bean` just to represent something that I already have in the bean, like : `bean.priceDay`, `bean.priceWeek`, `bean.priceMonth`. I just would like to swtich between these `prices` based on the selected `price`.

Comment: So.. Essentially, you do not want to have a bean property? Perhaps because you're not using it for other purposes?

Comment: I update my post, to help why I think this approach is 'inelegant'

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how the code snippet added during the update is related to the initial code snippet.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding Bauke, update my code again =].

Comment: *confused* cannot understand the question and comments! :-/

Comment: I think what he is trying to say is, and correct me if I am wrong, since he already has the values in the BeanModel object, he is not too happy about creating another property in the managedBean to hold the same value.

Comment: @leo21, that's exactly what I'm trying to say here, thank you!

Comment: I think I finally understand the question. The confusion is caused because he incorrectly used `#{beanC.price}` as both dropdown and output value while that's plain impossible when considering the concrete functional requirement. In other words, the OP did not post real code at all. Valter, you should instead have posted the real code in SSCCE flavor in order to point out the "inelegantness" of the approach. This is what everyone was expecting.

Comment: I've improved the question. Is this indeed what you're concretely asking? Please rollback the edit if this is not the case.

Comment: No, that's OK Bauke, thank once more my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the brace notation `[]` in EL to reference bean properties by a dynamic property name.

This should do:

```
<h:selectOneMenu binding="#{priceType}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Price" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="priceDay" itemLabel="day" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="priceWeek" itemLabel="week" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="priceMonth" itemLabel="month" />
    <f:ajax render="price" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:panelGroup id="price">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.rent[priceType.value]}" rendered="#{not empty priceType.value}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

This way you can get rid of `priceType` and `price` properties and `changePrice()` method in your bean.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, comparing strings (and objects in general) by value should not be done by `compareTo()` method, but by `equals()` instead.